# FOR UPDATE cannot be specified on a READ ONLY cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm using a cursor to update a single field in a table, and I'm attempting to declare the cursor using an `ORDER BY` in the text of the select.

I've got the following example data:

```
testTable:
RecordGuid RecordID DupeParentID
---------- -------- ------------
[guid]     A        Y
[guid]     A        N
[guid]     A        N
[guid]     A        N
[guid]     B        Y
[guid]     B        N
[guid]     B        N
[guid]     C        Y
[guid]     C        N
[guid]     C        N
```

And script:

```
DECLARE @allcounter INT
SET @allcounter = 1

SELECT RecordID, count(*) as [NumberDupes]
INTO #RecordGroupCounts
FROM testTable
GROUP BY RecordID

DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @current VARCHAR(500)

DECLARE c1 CURSOR 
FOR 
    SELECT RecordID FROM testTable WHERE RecordID IN (SELECT RecordID FROM testTable WHERE DupeParentID = 'Y') 
    ORDER BY RecordID
FOR UPDATE OF RecordID

OPEN c1

FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @current
FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @current

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE testTable
    SET RecordID = RecordID + '-' + cast(@allcounter AS VARCHAR)
    WHERE CURRENT OF c1

    IF (@allcounter + 1) = (SELECT [NumberDupes] FROM #RecordGroupCounts WHERE RecordID = @current)
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @current
        SET @allcounter = 0
    END 
    SET @allcounter = @allcounter + 1

    FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @current
END
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
```

The desired output of all of this is:

```
RecordGuid RecordID DupeParentID
---------- -------- ------------
[guid]     A        Y
[guid]     A-1      N
[guid]     A-2      N
[guid]     A-3      N
[guid]     B        Y
[guid]     B-1      N
[guid]     B-2      N
[guid]     C        Y
[guid]     C-1      N
[guid]     C-2      N
```

I'm working with SQL Server 2000 so I don't have `ROW_NUMBER()` available - I know the common way to do this is with loops, but I am by no means a DBA, and this currently works if I remove my `ORDER BY RecordID` in the cursor declaration.

With as small as my current test table is this seems to be working fine, but the reason I'm attempting to order this is that I'm fairly sure it'll break if the RecordIDs aren't in order (by `RecordID ASC, DupeParentID DESC`) and I intend to use this on a much larger set of records semi-regularly.  Is there a way to define the order for a cursor that updates?  Is the cursor ordered automatically somehow?  If not, is there a simpler (or faster) way to write this for SQL Server 2000?

Comment: I'm not sure if I see where a lack of order by on the record_id would break this.  Although it would appear the order in which the duplicates are marked as -1 -2 -3 etc... is a bit arbitrary.  The faster way to write this would be with a lack of a loop and turn it into something set based, but that might be challenging.   As a complete side note, your population of the c1 cursor can be redone to SELECT RecordID FROM testTable WHERE DupeParentID = 'Y' group by recordID (the group will eliminate duplicates, I suspect that was your goal with the where in).

Comment: @Tewlfth - currently (with the order by), I get the specified error message.  Without it, after some testing, it runs, but it appears the cursor doesn't order the data at all, and so my counter updates records with an incorrect number (I get things like `A, A-1, A-2, C-3, A, C-1, C-2`...).  As for the `DupeParentID = 'Y'`, I need every record that has a RecordID of `DupeParentID = 'Y'` (for the cursor itself) - not just the 'Y' records, but all of them matching a RecordID with a Y.

Comment: Was hoping someone else would take a run at answering this...the mix of non-unique data and a cursor is pretty brutal.  Mind if I try a different angle on this?  Correct me if I'm wrong, but you currently have data in a table and this script is being used as a one time correction (IE, you don't plan on using this logic in on-going prod)...if that's the case, I do have another idea for you to handle this.  Is their anything in the 'testable' to differentiate the 3 recordID A Dupeparent_id N, or do you actually have 3 identical records to number here?

Comment: @Tewlfth so it turns out I forgot a key piece of information - there's a primary key which includes a uniqueidentifier for each of these records (I just didn't include it because it wasn't directly relevant to how I was updating).  I'll update to reflect that...

Comment: My assumptions otherwise right?   I'll put together a more set based solution (kinda needs the loop, but should perform much better.  The guide (I assume big int) will be needed for the update portion...will start writing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select recordid, max(recordguid)
from testable
where DupeParentID = 'N'
group by recordID
```

The above statement should return 1 row per recordID with the max(guID) for that recordID. heh, spell check keeps changing guid to guide.   Now we can increment all of these with the 1.

```
update testtable 
set recordID = recordID + '-1'
where recordguid in (select recordguid from (    select recordid, max(recordguid) recordguid
from testable
where DupeParentID = 'N'
group by recordID) a)
```

Get the logic here?  What we're doing is taking the first duplicate ID using the max recordguid as an identifier for the 'first'...lil arbitrary, we could use min as well as long as it returns just one guID for each recordID.  If you had some other logic as to which record was to be called the -1 vs the -2, you can include it here.

This will create all the recordID-1 (A-1,B-1) and leave the rest alone.  Now you should be able to loop this and increment the -1 as needed...or you could just repeat run it manually incrementing the -1 yourself if this is a one time fix...your call there.

Let me know how it goes...the logic should work and will be quite quicker than going through each recordID at a time.

Comment: Interesting idea - using this I think I can rewrite it to use only a single while loop.  This is going to be run in production against a table with hundreds of thousands of records (though likely only hundreds will need updating), so I'm trying to keep it pretty lean.  I'll try it out later tonight/tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: If it helps any, hundreds of thousands is kinda small for this :)    If you wanted, you can set a variable to represent the maximum amount of repetitions you'll have to go through prior to the loop.  Select max(rowcount) from (select recordID,count(1) as rowcount from testtable where duplicateparentID = 'N' group by recordID)a.    This will dynamically assign the amount of repetitions your query needs to loop through.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. Although I do not expect performance to be to great, so I would not recomend this solution if you need to run the query on production on regular basis.

```
declare @counter int ,@continue tinyint
set @counter =1 
set @continue = 1
while @continue = 1
Begin 
    update testtable 
    set testtable.recordid = testtable.recordid + ' - ' + CAST (@counter as nchar(6))
    from 
    testtable 
    inner join
    (  
    select  MAX(cast(t1.guid as char(36)))  as maxguid from testtable t1
    inner join testtable t2 on t1.recordid = t2.recordid 
    where
    t2.dupeparentid = 'y' and  t1.dupeparentid = 'n'
    group by t1.recordid
    ) t4

    on testtable.guid = cast (t4.maxguid as uniqueidentifier)

    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    set @continue = 0
    set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```